# android : facebook login using facebook sdk 3 with no facebook app installed

Tags: android, facebook, authentication

I am using facebook sdk 3 in my app. I want to fetch some user info to be used in my app. It is working good if i have the facebook app installed in my device. It ask for login, if it's not logged in and works. But i want my app to work even if no facebook app is installed on the device . How can i do it.  My code is below. Please help

```
Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

        // callback when session changes state
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                Exception exception) {
            if (session.isOpened()) {
                // make request to the /me API
                Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session,
                        new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                            // callback after Graph API response with user
                            // object
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(GraphUser graphuser,
                                    Response response) {
                                L
                                if (graphuser != null) {
                                    GraphObject graphObject = response
                                            .getGraphObject();
                                    Log.i(" facebookLogin Email is ",
                                            "value"
                                                    + graphObject
                                                            .getProperty("email"));
                                    User user = getUserDetails(graphObject,
                                            graphuser.getId());
                                    sendFBCredentialsToServer(user);
                                    updateSharedPrefsWithFacebookCredentials(user);

                                }
                            }

                        });
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Pls wait , Fetching data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// Add code to print out the key hash


try {
PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
        "com.your.packagename", 
        PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
    md.update(signature.toByteArray());
    Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));// g
    }
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

}
```

add this code on onCreate and get the Hash key from facebook and replace this key on app settings on facebook

Answer (score 0):

Add Facebook LoginButton in your main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/loginButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Login With Facebook" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Now, whenever you click on facebook loginbutton it open facebook app if installed otherwise open facebook login page in webview

onCreate

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

   LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
   authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("email","user_about_me"));

}
```

onSessionStateChange

```
private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
             if( session.isOpen())
                  getUserData();

}
public void getUserData()
{
Request.executeMeRequestAsync(Session.getActiveSession(), 
                              new GraphUserCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {

            Log.d("FNAME", user.getFirstName());
            Log.d("LNAME", user.getLastName());
            Log.d("GENDER",user.getProperty("gender").toString());
            Log.d("EMAIL_ID",user.getProperty("email").toString());
            Log.d("FACEBOOK_ID",user.getId());
             }                  
    });
 }
```

Comment: I want to call getUserData soon after login .. How can i get to know in code login is finished. ie my logic is press a button : login if not logged in and fetch data

Comment: thank you. i did similar change, but i see that onSessionStateChange is never getting called.